# scala:encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import

Tags: scala

why do I face  encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import? I commented out the object definition ,but still doens't work. The code is non-sense, but just want to know why it doesn't compile.

```
object abc
{
 trait test[T]{
   def prt(x:T):Unit
}
//object test
  val b="hello word"
}

object my extends App{
   import abc._
   def abc[O]=new test[O]{
     def prt(x:Int)=println("testabcd")
   }
   println(b)
   println("test1")
}


sbt run
[info] Set current project to myfirstproject (in build file:/D:/my/test/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to D:\my\test\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] D:\my\test\Hello.scala:11: encountered unrecoverable cycle resolving import.
[error] Note: this is often due in part to a class depending on a definition nested within its companion.
[error] If applicable, you may wish to try moving some members into another object.
[error]    import abc._
[error]           ^
[error] D:\my\test\Hello.scala:15: not found: value b
[error]    println(b)
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Apr 16, 2014 4:45:35 AM
```

Comment: apart from importing, `def abc[O]=new test[O]` is a nonsense expression which is not supported by scala syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense and that is why it does not compile :)

You are importing `abc` then trying to redefine first element from package (`def abc[0]`?), and after that you are trying to create instance of trait `new test[O]` giving value `0` instead of type.